# Regex to capture a sentence with a target phrase

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am using C# to find a phrase that may or may not exists in a blog posting. I need to capture the whole sentence that contains the target phrase.

I thought about using the string.contains method but that would return the whole blog post when all I want is the target phrase and its containing sentence.

Example:

```
I dont want this sentence. I also don't want this setence. But I do want this sentence.
```

So here the target phrase would be: "I do" and the regex should return the whole containing sentence "But I do want this sentence."

Thanks.
Aaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex :

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"(?<=^|\.)[^.]*?(?=\bI do\b).*(\.|$)").Value;
```

When applied to your input :

```
I dont want this sentence. I also don't want this setence. But I do want this sentence.
```

Returns :

```
But I do want this sentence.
```

Turn on RegexOptions.Singleline if you worry about multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a *regex*, but you could use the combination of the `Split` function and the `Contains` function and write something like this:

```
string DoesBlogContainSentence(string blog, string target)
{
   string[] blogSentences = blog.Split(new char[] {'.'});

   foreach(string sentence in blogSentences)
   {
      if(sentence.Contains(target))
      {
          return sentence;
      }
   }

   return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Splitting on '.' alone wouldn't necessarily return sentences only. If you had a decimal number for example, this would be split.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the blog post into sentences and then search each sentence for the target phrase.

E.g.

```
  string data = "I dont want this sentence. I also don't want this setence. But I do want this sentence.";
  string targetPhrase = "I do";

  string[] sentences = Regex.Split(data, "\\.\\s");

  foreach (string sentence in sentences)
  {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(sentence, "\\s" + targetPhrase + "\\s"))
    {
      //.....
    }
  }
```